# Can I redirect a new domain to a specific pg without affecting that page's search standing?

Tags: seo, url, search-engine-indexing, search-results, multiple-domains

I want to redirect a new domaim (that has not been used before) to a specific page on a site which already has good standing in search results - I want to do this instead of forwarding because I need the redirect to land on a page which is neither the index page or the index for a subdomain.  Is this possible to do this without affecting the good SEO status of the page that is being redirected to, and without that original page disappearing from the SERPs?

The idea is to use another domain name as a marketing slogan which promotes traffic to the existing page without changing the original page's standing in SERPS, so I'm also wondering if BOTH URLs will appear in search results using different queries.

Comment: Yeah... this does not sound like a good idea. I will let someone else answer, but these SEO tricks are often a horrible idea. I personally would not do it.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain that you are redirecting has no bad history (has never hosted porn, gambling, been penalised by Google, etc) then simply redirecting it wont have any adverse effects on the page you are redirecting it too.

However when you 301 redirect a page, you are telling Google that the page has permanently  moved, so the page will no longer appear in the SERPs.

You could potentially use a temporary 302 redirect, as pages that 302 redirect generally stay in the SERPS. However for this to work, you would first need to create a site on the domain you want to redirect, wait for it to get indexed in Google then 302 redirect it. But having said that I wouldn't recommended doing this, as Google can frown upon 302 redirects and if they think you are trying to do something untoward, the page that it's being redirected too could potentiality be adversely effected.  Also I doubt the the site being 302 redirected would rank for any searches.

I'd recommended against trying to get them both to appear in the SERPS, but simply redirecting a domain to another is fine and common practice.